# A '60s(?) era sci-fi episode/film about a jungle with robotic duplicates?

Tags: story-identification, tv, b-movies

I know this is pretty vague, but I have been looking for this movie/tv show episode for my entire life. I first saw this when I was about 3 or 4. It gave me absolute nightmares and although I have very little memory of anything about it, the few things I do remember are as follows:

A man is trying to rescue a girl from a tribe in a jungle. The tribe are not human; they have mechanical pulleys inside their chests and tapes(?) whirling around in them. The pulleys in their chests are like mechanical motors or something to that extent and move up and down.

The hero is running away through this jungle, after rescuing the woman. She had been previously captured, but he found her and escaped with her. As they are running and being pursued, the girl trips and falls and I think she passes out or faints, or something to that effect. This causes the hero to turn her over or undo her jacket or top, revealing her open chest with those pulleys inside bouncing about, revealing that she too was a robot. She may have been turned into one, was one all along, or she is a duplicate.

The man/hero who was trying to save her had a William Shatner look. It may even have been him as I will get to. But I'm honestly not sure.

I seem to remember the tribesmen looking very much like zulus. Again this could be false memory.

In my endless search for what this nightmare fuel was, I have been lead to several possibilities. Some were dead ends, some still unconfirmed.

First suggestion was *Doctor Who - Android Invasion*. Very similar 'idea's but certainly not the one. I know *Who* very well so I really dont think this was the show.

Also several *Star Trek TOS* episodes. *What Are Little Girls Made Of?*, *That Which Survives*, and there was another about a robot that looks human I have forgotten the title of. I cannot confirm these, as I am not a Trek expert and do not have access to these episodes currently. If anyone does, please help me confirm.

*Twilight Zone* and *Outer Limits*. I've seen most of these with very few exceptions but I will not rule this out. Again if anyone e has seen the 6 robot themed *Twilight Zones* it would help. I have seen *The Lonely*, again similar sort of reveal but not the one.

I think this film/series was colour, but again I'm not 100 percent.

I'm 95 percent sure it was 1960s. It  could have been '50s or '70s, but I'm thinking '60s.

Comment: _The Twilight Zone_ and the 1963-65 _Outer Limits_ series were filmed in black and white and the episode doesn't sound familiar. _The Stepford Wives_ is a movie with women replaced by robots, but I haven't seen it.

Comment: The Stepford Wives is a film I am quite familiar with. The horror in that movie is the very same 'vibe' I got from this one I am trying to find. The setting is very different but it does share that kind of idea. I wish I could remember if the robots were replacements or duplicates or something else but sadly memory fails me. I am sure of one thing above all else though. The definitelly had these pulley/motor things inside them. I remember thinking they looked like primitive steam powered engines with tape/bands and so on. Gave me absolute nightmares. I long to see it again in adulthood.

Comment: It's almost been another year but still there has been no conclusion...

Comment: It's been almost another year but still no luck finding this. Has anyone got any  more leads?

Comment: _The Six Million Dollar Man_ had a couple of story arcs involving ["fembots"](https://bionic.fandom.com/wiki/Fembot), robots mostly built to resemble women. The final part of the first story takes place partly on a jungle island, as I recall.

Comment: The description of the scene where the woman is revealed to be a robot reminds me of a similar scene late in [_Halloween III: Season of the Witch_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085636/).

Answer (score 1):

The only one I could find close to that is The Outer Limits The Demon with a Glass Hand, it's not quite right but it's close. https://www.solie.org/alibrary/OuterLimits_205DemonWithaGlassHand.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).